# Converting bool expression to char in c#

Tags: c#, clr

I passed .NET quiz, when I met a question like below one.

```
Char ch = Convert.ToChar('a' | 'e' | 'c' | 'a');
```

In console we can see that output for `ch` variable is `g`.

Can someone describe what is happening ?
Thanks!

Comment: Those oeprators are called bitwise operators. Basically they "combine" your four characters *bitwise* to a new number which is then converted to character. So what happens when you add the bits of all those characters?

Comment: It is kind of dissapointed thing for me just now, cause I see the type of variable that contains expression, which I wrote - int.

Comment: I know this might sound obvious - but that's a terrible quiz question to ask in a .NET quiz.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum

Why do you think so ?

Comment: @VladislavHromyh because it does not test for any skill a proficient C# developer needs. Instead it tests you remembering that you can treat chars as numbers, remember the ASCII code of `a` `e` and `c` (or remember a is 97 at least and that it's sequential) and remember that it's safe to bitwise or these values since although chars are 16 bit in this particular case they're treated like ASCII and the conversion works in the other way too. I happened to remember this - but I have not used any of these tricks in 4 years of developing C# at all - and I likely won't in the next 4 either.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum that depends on if the question was "what is ch" or "what happened". I would expect from every non-novice programmer to know that 'characters' can get converted to numbers and bitwise or'd.

Comment: This is why programmers should cut their teeth on assembler, or at least C, before moving to those lovely, convenient, high productivity languages like C#. Yes, this has diddly-squat to do with typical C#.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is not what it looks like at first spot. It is more of binary calculations on the `int` representation of these `Char`:

Here is a full article explaining this with examples: [Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/544990/Understand-how-bitwise-operators-work-Csharp-and-V)

So the binary result for the bitwise `Or` of these `'a' | 'e' | 'c' | 'a'` is `103`. If you Convert that to Char, it is `g`

**Edit:**

I see this answer took more attention than I though it deserves more details.

### From C# Compiler side:

There is an implicit conversion from char to int (`int i = 'a'` compiles), so what the compiler actually does is:

```
Convert.ToChar((int)'a' | (int)'e' | (int)'c' | (int)'a');
```

Since these are hard-coded values, the compiler does more work:

```
Convert.ToChar(97 | 101 | 99 | 97);
```

and finally:

```
Convert.ToChar(103); // g
```

**If these were not hard-coded values:**

```
private static char BitwiseOr(char c1, char c2, char c3, char c4)
{
    return Convert.ToChar(c1 | c2 | c3 | c4);
}
```

Using Roslyn you get:

```
private static char BitwiseOr(char c1, char c2, char c3, char c4)
{
    return Convert.ToChar((int)c1 | c2 | c3 | c4);
}
```

**Converted to IL** (`or` (Bitwise) IL instruction used):

```
.method private hidebysig static char  BitwiseOr(char c1,
                                                   char c2,
                                                   char c3,
                                                   char c4) cil managed
  {
    // 
    .maxstack  2
    .locals init (char V_0)
    IL_0000:  nop
    IL_0001:  ldarg.0
    IL_0002:  ldarg.1
    IL_0003:  or
    IL_0004:  ldarg.2
    IL_0005:  or
    IL_0006:  ldarg.3
    IL_0007:  or
    IL_0008:  call       char [mscorlib]System.Convert::ToChar(int32)
    IL_000d:  stloc.0
    IL_000e:  br.s       IL_0010

    IL_0010:  ldloc.0
    IL_0011:  ret
  } // end of method Program::BitwiseOr
```

Comment: +1 nicely brought to attention that it is not a direct of conversion of bool to a char, but a binary calculation.

Answer (score 34):

"|" is the binary OR operator.

```
'a' binary representation is 01100001
'e' binary representation is 01100101
'c' binary representation is 01100011
```

The result of the `OR` is `01100111`, whose char representation is `g`

Comment: I agree, but here problem is why it's gives 'g' or 01100111 binary

Comment: There was a 4 char value, wasn't it ?
Is result the same ?

Comment: The OR operator gives these results:
0 | 0 = 0
0 | 1 = 1
1 | 0 = 0
1 | 1 = 1

Comment: @VladislavHromyh The `'a'` is present twice in the original question, but ORing anything with itself just leaves the original value (`0|0==0` and `1|1==1`) so you only need to look at the three distinct values.

Comment: Actually, all of those are 16 bit and not 8 bit since this is c#.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum 0 OR 0 equals 0, so the suffix of 0 can be ignored for the sake of this question.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, since this is UTF-16, you mean. This behavior isn't exclusive to C#.

Comment: Simply because it was the first

Answer (score 10):

Go to [unicode-table](http://unicode-table.com/en/#control-character).

- `'a'` Decimal value is **97** in binary it's `01100001`.
- `'e'` Decimal value is **101** in binary it's `01100101`.
- `'c'` Decimal value is **99** in binary it's `01100011`.
- `'a'`  Decimal value is **97** in binary it's `01100001`.

**Or** operator in bit wise is `'|'`.
So your expression is equal to:

`01100001` **OR** 
`01100101` **OR** 
`01100011` **OR** 
`01100001` and the result for this is 
 `01100111`.

**Or** results **1** if there is at least one time **1** in the column.

`01100001` converting to Decimal is **103**.
We will go again to the [unicode-table](http://unicode-table.com/en/#control-character) and we will see that **103** in deciaml is equal to `'g'`.

So you asked what that function does, it calculates the binary value then converts it to Decimal value and returns the **unicode** character of it.

Comment: But we can see that type of var n = ('c' | 'a') is int, innit ?
Does it matter in that example ? I think yes. Am I not right ?

Comment: @VladislavHromyh, that's why you use `Convert.ToChar()`, to cast the int back into a character.

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez

So, is it true, that we use overloaded ToChar() method with int parameter ? And, respectively, bitwise operators between chars return int ?

Comment: @VladislavHromyh, Yes, that's right. Bitwise operators implicitly convert chars to ints, but going back requires an explicit conversion.