# Syntax when accessing array of strings

Tags: c#

With the following:

```
string[] strArr = {
    "SOMETHING",
    "ELSE",
    "HERE"
};
var a = strArr['B' - 'A'];
```

What exactly is going on with the `['B' - 'A']`, and where can I find documentation of this behavior?

Comment: why downvotes? I didn't make the code, I'm just trying to figure out someone else's mess.

Comment: I just upvoted.  I can't stand when people down vote because they think you should know something that you don't know.  Not a reason to down vote.  And nobody knows everything.

Comment: AND you just got a close vote for "why is this code not working"...which obviously wasn't your question.  Update: it's gone now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is implicitly converting character codes to integers. It is a terrible way to represent the number 1, being that B is 66 and A is 65.

The end result is that you get the [1] element ("ELSE").

This works because char implements the `IConvertible` interface, and has this supporting method

```
/// <internalonly/>
int IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider) {
    return Convert.ToInt32(m_value);
}
```

More at [char.cs<sup>reference source</sup>](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/char.cs)

Answer (score 2):

There is an [implicit conversion from `char` to `int`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx).  The conversion from char to int gives you the UTF-16 code of that character.  Since `B` (ASCII 66) is the next letter after `A` (ASCII 65) in UTF-16, `B` - `A` would be equal to `42-41` which would be `1`.

so

```
strArr['B' - 'A']
```

is equivalent to

```
strArr[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

As for the documentation, try [char (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9h8tsay.aspx).

First, `'B'` and `'A'`, which are character literals stored as 16 bit numbers, will resolve to a `char` with the value `1`.

Second, the compiler recognizes that the expression `'B' - 'A'` is of type `char`, but `string[]` has an indexer which takes an argument of type `int`. As noted in the documentation above, the `char` type can be implicitly converted to an `int`; so this is the choice the compiler makes.

Comment: You can also read more about [implicit conversion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

In C#, there is a implicit conversion from char not int (but not the opposite). So `int x = 'a';` compiles. Actually the compiler transforms your code to something else. Here is and original code, and the code generated by the compiler:

User Code:

```
string[] strArr = { "SOMETHING", "ELSE", "HERE" };
char left = 'B';
char right = 'A';
int index = left - right;
var a = strArr[index];
```

Generated Compiler code:

```
string[] strArr = { "SOMETHING", "ELSE", "HERE" };
char c = 'B';
char c2 = 'A';
int num = (int)c - c2; // 66 - 65
string text = array[num];
```

I wrote a details [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38178498/converting-bool-expression-to-char-in-c-sharp/38178752#38178752) about this a week go. Check it out.